# Why would my router internal network address conflict with the fibre modem?

Tags: networking, router

I'm having my new router `R` under the fibre model `F`.

- `F` internal address is 192.168.1.1, external address is normal pubic IP address
- `R` internal address is 192.168.1.1, external address is dynamically configured

the end result is that

- `R` detects and reports the IP address conflict and reset its internal address to 10.0.0.1

my understanding: `R` and `F` constitutes two different subnet. I assume they don't interfere with each other, the external internal address mapping is done via NAT.

my questions :

- why would `R` 192.168.1.1 conflict with `F` ?
- How come 10.0.0.1 which is bigger net sits under 192.168.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

> why would `R` 192.168.1.1 conflict with `F`?

Because `R` to communicate with `F` needs to send packets to 192.168.1.1. So if 192.168.1.1 is both: `F`'s address and `R`'s address, there is a conflict.

The fact that `R` performs NAT does not mean `R` itself can be connected to two networks with the same addressing. To work properly it needs to be connected to two different networks (directing traffic between two distinct networks is the very definition of routing).

> How come 10.0.0.1 which is bigger net sits under 192.168.1.1?

These are two separate networks. Neither is "sitting under" the other.

Besides, the network "size" is not determined by the address of a single interface, but a netmask.

Comment: for the first question, isn't R facing F with a different ip address ? and the external and internal is converted through NAT ?